# Watchkit App: UI measures

Tags: user-interface, watchkit

I am trying to lay out the basics for a Watchkit app. I am trying to figure out the measures I have to keep into account, like height of the screen minus status bar and so on. I cannot find, though, any place where these specification are written. Something like [iDev 101](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html) Is anyone aware of such a resource and could share?

Comment: Have you tried Apple's [official design resources](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one, it helped me on the way. Even though you don't need to consider it as much as for the phone when the design choices are pretty strict.

https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/specifications/

In addition, it's possible to download the psd layout projects [here](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/resources/).